# PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: after deploying rails app using passenger, nginx and capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, nginx, passenger

After a resent deploy of a `Rails`application to a `Ubuntu 16.04.1 x64` `VPS` the server is not able to start.  Since yesterday I've been trying to solve why, but without any luck. Now I'm totally helpless and out of options.

The deploy stops at:

`deploy:migrating
      01 $HOME/.rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle exec rake db:migrate
      01 rake aborted!
      01 PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
      01    Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
      01    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`

Because of this error messages I've changed the settings in the `pg_hba.conf` and the `postgresql.conf` to the following examples according to this article http://www.railszilla.com/postgresql-tcpip-connections-port-5432/coffee-break

```
`pg_hba.conf`
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0       trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

And the `postgresql.conf` settings (See below).

```
# - Connection Settings -

listen_addresses = '*'          # what IP address(es) to listen on;
                                    # comma-separated list of addresses;
                                    # defaults to 'localhost'; use '*' for all
                                    # (change requires restart)
port = 5432                             # (change requires restart)
max_connections = 100                   # (change requires restart)
#superuser_reserved_connections = 3     # (change requires restart)
unix_socket_directories = '/var/run/postgresql' # comma-separated list of 
directories
                                    # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_group = ''                 # (change requires restart)
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777         # begin with 0 to use octal notation
                                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour = off                          # advertise server via Bonjour
                                    # (change requires restart)
#bonjour_name = ''                      # defaults to the computer name
                                    # (change requires restart)

# - Security and Authentication -
```

And after restarting by `sudo service postgresql restart` I still get the same error after deploying again.

**Update, database.yml from server**
Here is the `database.yml` from the server.

```
production:
 adapter: postgresql
 host: 127.0.0.1
 database: databasename
 username: username
 password: password
 encoding: unicode
 pool: 5
```

In the `/var/log/nginx/error.log` the last line is like this `[ 2017-09-27 13:09:13.4321 1530/7fa87d58e700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 1-149] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is c620ca8b. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.`

As it says I checked out earlier logs. Below is the whole log.  It is reffering to a `order_notifier.rb`  witch is supposed to have a bad syntax.

here is the whole log for the error `c620ca8b` :

```
    [ 2017-09-27 13:02:37.1572 1530/7fa87d58e700 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:285 ]: [Client 1-148] Cannot checkout session because a spawning error occurred. The identifier of the error is 446bb8e9. Please see earlier logs for details about the error.
App 20925 stdout:
App 20925 stdout:
[ 2017-09-27 13:09:13.4236 1530/7fa88401a700 age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/current: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: c620ca8b
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-Mirupe.html
  Message from application: /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/releases/20170926133751/app/mailers/order_notifier.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
    mail (to: order.email, subject: 'Hlin Reykdal Concept Store',
             ^
/home/deploy/hlinreykdal/releases/20170926133751/app/mailers/order_notifier.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
    mail (to: order.email, subject: 'Hlin Reykdal Concept Store',
                                   ^
/home/deploy/hlinreykdal/releases/20170926133751/app/mailers/order_notifier.rb:8: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
    mail (to: order.email, subject: 'Hlin Reykdal Concept Store',
                                                                 ^
/home/deploy/hlinreykdal/releases/20170926133751/app/mailers/order_notifier.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
/home/deploy/hlinreykdal/releases/20170926133751/app/mailers/order_notifier.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
    mail (to: order.email, subject: 'Order Shipped')
             ^
/home/deploy/hlinreykdal/releases/20170926133751/app/mailers/order_notifier.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
    mail (to: order.email, subject: 'Order Shipped')
                                   ^
/home/deploy/hlinreykdal/releases/20170926133751/app/mailers/order_notifier.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:244:in `rescue in load_dependency'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in `load_dependency'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
  /home/deploy/hlinreykdal/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
```

And here is the `order_notifier.rb` I can´t see what is wrong whit it, maybe someone here can.

```
class OrderNotifier < ApplicationMailer

   default from: 'Hlin Reykdal Concept Store <hlin@hlinreykdal.com>'

    def received(order)
     @order = order
     mail (to: order.email, subject: 'Hlin Reykdal Concept Store')
    end

   def shipped(order)
    @order = order
    mail (to: order.email, subject: 'Order Shipped')
   end  
 end
```

I've restarted both the nginx by `sudo service nginx restart` and the app by `bundle exec passenger-config restart-app`  but with out a luck, still getting the same error if I deploy again.

I googled all over the web and looked at hundreds of posts here on stack. Nothing seems to work.  Now I'm getting really desperate about this.  I've had similar problems before after a deploy, but I've always managed to fix it, but this seems to be aout of my league.

**UPDATE**

It seems like the `production log` is stuck in `23/5 2017`  even after all my restarts and deploys. It seems like it is stuck in an error from the mailer??

```
I, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.741054 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal 
Server Error in 66ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)
F, [2017-05-23T11:01:44.743481 #1060] FATAL -- :
 SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known):
 app/admin/order.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'


I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.863192 #1060]  INFO -- : Started GET "/products/41" for 164.132.161.46 at 2017-05-23 11:10:08 +0000
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.876373 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by ProductsController#show as */*
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.876536 #1060]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"41"}
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.881123 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mCart Load (0.7ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", nil]]
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.882685 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36m (0.2ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mBEGIN^[[0m
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.887770 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mSQL (1.3ms)^[[0m  INSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"  [["created_at", "2017-05-23 11:10:08.883411"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-23 11:10:08.883411"]]
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.890018 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36m (0.7ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mCOMMIT^[[0m
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.893274 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mProduct Load (1.2ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."slug" = $1  ORDER BY "products"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["slug", "41"]]
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.894865 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mProduct Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["id", 41]]
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.900733 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mLabel Load (1.2ms)^[[0m  SELECT  "labels".* FROM "labels" WHERE "labels"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 8]]
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.907954 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mProduct Load (0.6ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."category_id" = $1  ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 6^[[0m  [["category_id", 12]]
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.916955 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered products/show.html.erb within layouts/application (18.7ms)
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.920965 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35mCategory Load (0.8ms)^[[0m  SELECT "categories".* FROM "categories"
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.924524 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mLabel Load (0.3ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT "labels".* FROM "labels"^[[0m
D, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.929926 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.3ms)^[[0m  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "product_items" WHERE "product_items"."cart_id" = $1  [["cart_id", 46319]]
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.930159 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_navbar.html.erb (10.7ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.931046 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_message.html.erb (0.2ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.932261 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered emaillist/_email.html.erb (0.6ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.932381 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_notifications.html.erb (0.9ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.936424 #1060]  INFO -- :   Rendered application/_footer.html.erb (3.5ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:10:08.936826 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 60ms (Views: 36.7ms | ActiveRecord: 7.6ms)
I, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.005157 #1060]  INFO -- : Started GET "/labels/10" for 66.249.65.74 at 2017-05-23 11:12:35 +0000
I, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.040137 #1060]  INFO -- : Processing by LabelsController#show as HTML
I, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.040544 #1060]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"10"}
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.049755 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mCart Load (0.8ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["id", nil]]
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.052776 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.2ms)^[[0m  BEGIN
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.060048 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mSQL (0.9ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mINSERT INTO "carts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING "id"^[[0m  [["created_at", "2017-05-23 11:12:35.053857"], ["updated_at", "2017-05-23 11:12:35.053857"]]
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.061486 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[35m (0.6ms)^[[0m  COMMIT
D, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.065373 #1060] DEBUG -- :   ^[[1m^[[36mLabel Load (0.4ms)^[[0m  ^[[1mSELECT  "labels".* FROM "labels" WHERE "labels"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1^[[0m  [["id", 10]]
I, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.067624 #1060]  INFO -- : Completed 404 Not Found in 27ms (ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
F, [2017-05-23T11:12:35.069957 #1060] FATAL -- :
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Label with 'id'=10):
  app/controllers/labels_controller.rb:21:in `set_label'
```

Comment: where are located the pg credentials? directly from database.yml, ENV vars or in your (nginx) server block?

Comment: @rogelio the pg files are in `etc/postgresql/9.5/main$ `  I added the `database.yml`to the question

Comment: Can you connect to PG with `psql -h localhost` from the shell? Also allowing any IP to connect to PG sounds like a really bad idea. You could use a UNIX socket instead of TCP/IP by setting `host: '/var/run/postgresql'` in `database.yml`.

Comment: @max  no when I do `psql -h localhost` I get this msg `psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`    Do you mean I just have to replace `host: 127.0.0.1` with `host: '/var/run/postgresql'`in the database.yml?

Comment: Yeah provided that you can connect via a socket at `/var/run/postgresql`

Comment: You should not have to do anything with the `postgresql.conf` though. Rails will connect fine with the default `listen_addresses = 'localhost'` unless you are using a very out of date version of the `pg` gem or the old deprechiated `postgres` gem instead. I would start with a fresh `postgresql.conf` or clean reinstall postgres with apt-get or whatever package manager is in place. Be very wary of following the advise of any blog or page without a published date as it can be badly out of date.

Comment: @max I changed the `listen_addresses = '*'` ` 'localhost'`,  and replaced `host: 127.0.0.1 with host: '/var/run/postgresql'` in the `database.yml`.  I restarted PG and NGINX, now the error has changed into `PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
 Is the server running locally and accepting
 connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?`

Comment: Does `psql -h localhost` work? In that case you can use `host: 'localhost'` instead of the socket.

Comment: `psql -h localhost` gives me the error : `psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused
 Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
 TCP/IP connections on port 5432?`  If I do a fresh re-install of postgres, what will happen to my Database? It can't be delete it as well if I re-install

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to fix my problem, after following the answer provided here : https://askubuntu.com/questions/810008/after-upgrade-14-04-to-16-04-1-postgresql-server-does-not-start

and then do the modifycations provided here : https://gist.github.com/GabLeRoux/0c60f9be0c28b6b41f64cb55474b0ccb

May app is up and running again...

Answer (score 1):

`rm /usr/local/var/postgres/postmaster.pid`

Restart Postgresql

`sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: the rm command sounds good, but I've restarted my Postgres with brew